# i want to retrieve data from db and need to dispaly in a table with edit and delete button?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

my admin.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .bod{
            background-color:#f8f8f8 ;
            border-shadow: 5px 10px 20px white inset;
            border-width:5px;
            margin-top:-12px;
        }
        .h1{
            font-family:"Book Antiqua";
            font-size: 90px;
            color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }
        div {
            border-radius: 5px;
            /*background-color: #f2f2f2;*/
            /*background-color: #7CA8C1  ;*/
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
            border:2px solid white;
            height: 200px;
            width: 50%;
            margin-left: 50px;

        }
        .txt{
            width: 150px;
            height:25px;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
        .btn{
            width: 100px;
            height:28px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bod">
<h1 class="h1">Admin</h1>
<div align="left">

    <form action="{{ route('addCategory') }}" method="get">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <label for="category" style="font-family: 'Book Antiqua';font-size: 48px;color: #9999FF;">Category</label> <br/>
        <table class="table ">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input class="txt" type="text" name="category" id="category" placeholder="Enter the Category" ></td>
                <td align="center"></td>
                <td align="center"> <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="ADD" class="btn"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
$results = DB::table('category')
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Category Name</th>
        </tr>
                foreach ($category as $results)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {$results -> $dis}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my category model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "category";
    protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
    ];

}
```

my admin controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $a = '';
        return view('admin/admin',[
            'category' => $a
        ]);

        // echo "here";
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function addCategory()
    {
        $category = new Category;
        $category->category_name = Input::get('category');

        $category->save();
        return Redirect::to('admin');
    }
}
```

i want to get the all categories from db and  i need to display that in the same page in a tabular manner with delete and edit button?
i tried the above code but i am unable to get displayed it shows me the for each loops in the display instead of table

how can i achieve that?

Comment: I've never used Laravel so could be well off the mark but I'd assume that PHP code still needs to be within PHP tags - such as `$results = DB::table('category')` should be `<?php $results = DB::table('category');?>` and so forth

Answer (score 0):

you need to try in show method

```
public function show()
    {
        $category=Category::all();
        return view('your view name')->withCategory($category);

    }
```

and recieve the variable in view like that

```
 @foreach($category as $value)
   {{ $value->your field name }}
    @endforeach
```

Or for separate view redirect like that

```
return redirect()->route('separate route name')->withCategory($category);
```

Comment: i want show that in a existing page so do i need to create a separate view for it?

Comment: what is problem redirect with route for separate view

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write all your requests in a repository. Your controllers must not contain logic code or DB requests. 
Doing a SELECT with Eloquent can be done like this :

```
$query = (new Category())->newQuery();

return $query->select('*')->get();
```

You should read the documentation if you want to get more informations about Query Builder : [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your view

```
<?php
$results = DB::table('category')->get();
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
           @foreach ($results as $result)

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{$result -> $dis}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
</table>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade)

Answer (score 0):

you want to retrieve data from db and need to display in a table with edit and delete button? its easy bro, just put button in foreach

table

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
            foreach ($category as $results)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{$results -> your_data_column}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <a href='edit?{{$results->id}}'><button>edit</button></a>
                       <a href='delete?{{$results->id}}'><button>delete</button></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
     </table>
```

your controller

```
    public function show()
    {
       $data['category'] = DB::table('category')->get();
       return view('admin/admin',$data);
    }
```